# Omitting negative pixels

Tags: matlab, pixel

Say that I have an image where there are some pixels whose values are negative. How can I omit those from the image representation in MATLAB?

I have assigned the negative values to the pixels manually as I don't need such pixels, and this need to omit them from the representation. I don't want them to be `0` or positive.

Comment: **`Pixel values can be negative`???**

Comment: What do you mean by "omit negative pixels from the representation"? What colour do you want for those pixels? They will necessarily have _some_ colour on screen

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are getting a negative pixels but, You can replace any value smaller from `0` in a vector to zero:

```
--> a=[-1,2,3,4,-55]
a =
  -1   2   3   4 -55
--> b = (a<0)
b =
 1 0 0 0 1
--> a = (a>0).*a
a =
 0 2 3 4 0
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand why the image pixels have negative values. I assume you are talking about general matrix instead.

You can **omit/remove these negative values** by using

```
myMatrix = myMatrix(myMatrix>=0);
```

<s>Or you can replace these negative values to 0 by</s>

<s>myMatrix(myMatrix<0) = 0;</s>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you will do with the image.

but, try with

```
myMat(myMat >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like assigning NaN or inf to them. Some plot functions in ML don't paint NaN or inf numbers. Beyond that, we're going to need to know what you want to do with the data.